# Does Visual Studio auto-complete conflict with Copilot

Tags: visual-studio, github-copilot

[I am getting the following problem](https://www.screencast.com/t/OdakfhbYt4) using Copilot in VisualStudio. (If you don't want to watch the video, it's inserting the Copilot code when I press TAB, but commenting out a bunch of the inserted code.)

What it shows:

```
public class DisallowedNameConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<DisallowedName>
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<DisallowedName> builder)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

What it inserts:

```
public class DisallowedNameConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<DisallowedName>
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    ///         public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<DisallowedName> builder)
    ///         {
    ///             throw new NotImplementedException();
    ///         }
    ///     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specific to Visual Studio Code, yes.

I have observed the same thing using python: There is a suggestion by copilot but then it immediately gets "vetoed" by autocomplete.

I [turned off quickSuggestions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense) in the editor config.

Comment: this question is not about VS Code. for a related VS Code question, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/76243327/11107541